# OpenGL ES xor mode for drawing

Tags: opengl-es

Does OpenGL ES have XOR drawing mode? I want to draw a cube in that mode, then draw a sphere intersected with the cube, and the output should be the part of cube and the part of sphere but with empty intersection.

Comment: ES doesn't have actual logical operations on pixels. Best option seems to be some stencil buffer trick. By the way, ES 1 or 2?

Comment: @ChristianRau could you provide any links on how to do that? Im using Cocos3D for iPhone, and it does not supports ES 2 for now, so the answer is ES 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you want the image space intersection of both objects after projection and not the actual geometric intersection of the cube with the sphere (since that's absolutely not what OpenGL is for), you can use the [stencil](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glStencilFunc.xml) [buffer](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glStencilOp.xml) for this:

First ensure you have a stencil buffer (depends on your context creation framework, don't know how Cocos3D does it, but OpenGL ES 1 itself supports stencil test). Then of course enable stenciling before doing the cube and sphere thing and also clear the stencil buffer at the start of the frame (probably together with your other buffers):

```
glClear(... | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
...
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

First we render the cube only into the stencil buffer, incrementing the stencil value (which starts at `0`) for each drawn pixel.

```
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE); //don't really draw anything
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, -1);    //always pass the test (default anyway)
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_INCR);  //increment for each drawn pixel
//draw object
```

Then we do the same for the sphere. After that the stencil buffer has a `1` everywhere a cube pixel or a sphere pixel is, and a `2` everywhere a cube and a sphere pixel is.

Then we just draw both things normally, but only where the stencil buffer is not `2` (or where it is `1` if you want), thus we don't draw anything at the intersection:

```
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);  //draw something
glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 2, -1);      //draw everywhere except at intersection
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);    //leave the stencil buffer as is
//draw cube
//draw sphere
```

Finally when finished, we disable the stencil test again (`glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)`).

This is just a basic example, but it should get you started with the quite powerful stencil buffer.

At the moment the whole thing is dependent on the depth test results, which means it is dependent on the order you draw your objects in. If you want it to be independent of depth (thus only considering their 2D screen projections), then you can either draw your objects without depth test, or set the second parameter of `glStencilOp` (which is the operation performed when the stencil test passes but the depth test fails) to `GL_INCR`, too.

At the moment it also only works if back-face culling is enabled, since otherwise the stencil value would be incremented twice for each object (at least if ignoring the depth), and things would be even worse for non-convex objects. Maybe you could also use other stencil operations to perform your task, but unfortunately OpenGL ES 1 doesn't seem to support binary operations on stencil values and neither wrapping operations (thus decrementing `0` is again `0`).

**EDIT:** Ok, you really want the geometric intersection (or rather difference it seems) between the 3D objects. Well then your problem is not solvable by OpenGL itself. OpenGL doesn't do anything else then draw simple primitives (points, lines and triangles) to the screen. It is neither a scene management system nor a geometry library. What you are trying to achieve is a not so simple task (though using simple objects like cubes and spheres certainly helps) and you probably need to look for some geometry library for boolean operations on meshes (or [*Constructive Solid Geomtry (CSG)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry)) that generates the appropriate geometric difference as a triangular mesh that you can then draw with OpenGL as usual.

Another option, similar to your mentioned concept of a *"3D stencil buffer"* would be to discretize space using a regular grid and thus subdivide your objects into small voxels (3D pixels, think of small boxes). On those discrete finite voxel sets boolean operations are pretty easy. But of course this approach comes at the cost of introducing discretization error and performance overhead (operating on voxels means operating on large data sets, ok CSG isn't easy either, but has probably better complexity than O(n^3)). And you also have to recreate a renderable object from the voxel set again, either using some surface extraction method to get a mesh again, or just drawing small points or boxes.

In the end using a proper CSG library is probably your best bet, either way OpenGL doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: thanks for so detailed answer, but I think I asked my question not correctly enough... I actually meant geometric intersection, and the word "space" was not for projected image, but for 3D space. To clarify: if operator was not "cube xor sphere" but "cube and not sphere" there should be drawn a part of cube with half-spherical seizure (in 3D). So I need somewhat like stencil buffer, not for flat image, but for 3D space. I started to doubt, if GL could handle it itself. And your post is very useful for me, though

Comment: @medvedNick Oh, then that changes everything and the problem in fact isn't realted to OpenGL at all, since as you know, OpenGL just draws simple things to the screen and nothing else.